# Can I get rid of <c:url> iibtag in jstl?

Tags: javascript, spring, jakarta-ee, jstl

So I inherited of an old J2EE project barely maintainable and one of my tasks is to move the JS contained in the JSP into JS files.

For the internationalization, I used jquery-i18n-properties to remove the usage of `"<spring:message ..>"` which works perfectly fine but I don't know how can I get rid of thos `"<c:url ...>"` from JSTL.

Is it at least possible? I tried to use simple url but it doesn't seems to work when it needs to call controller from the back end. If someone could help me it would be nice :)